# Java spring custom queries to mysql doesnt work properly

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, rest

Model:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "SliderRes")
public class SliderModel {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "obrazek")
    @Lob
    private String img;

    @Column(name = "tytul")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "opis")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name = "tlo")
    private String bg;
}
```

Service Class:

```
import intj.frontend.sellkon.model.SliderModel;
import intj.frontend.sellkon.repository.SliderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class SliderService {

    @Autowired
    private SliderRepository sliderRepository;

    public List<SliderModel> getOpis(){
        List<SliderModel> lstMovie = new ArrayList<SliderModel>();
        lstMovie = sliderRepository.getOpis();
        return  lstMovie;
    }
}
```

Repository Interace:

```
import intj.frontend.sellkon.model.SliderModel;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface SliderRepository extends JpaRepository<SliderModel,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT opis FROM slider_res s")
    List<SliderModel> getOpis();
}
```

Controller:

```
import intj.frontend.sellkon.Service.SliderService;
import intj.frontend.sellkon.model.SliderModel;
import intj.frontend.sellkon.repository.SliderRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class SliderController {

    @Autowired
    private SliderService sliderService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<SliderModel> getOpis(){
        List<SliderModel> ls = sliderService.getOpis();
        return ls;
    }
}
```

data from mysql after executing the query

```
opis
desc
```

When i start app i have error: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sellkonApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sliderRepository';

CRUD methods like findAll() are working properly. I am just starting my adventure with Java spirng, and this problem is difficult for me. Can someone tell what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error is on the query.

A way to fix it would be to inform that it is a native query and that it is the value. Something like this.

I tested here, and it worked as expected.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT opis FROM slider_res s", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getOpis();
```

or like this if you want to retrieve evertything from the table

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM slider_res", nativeQuery = true)
List<SliderModel> getAll();
```

I prefer doing it like native queries, because if you are familiar with using SQL directly it will be more "readable".

Answer (score 0):

Can you put here full stacktrace of error that you get?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sellkonApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sliderRepository';
```

It's only the top beginning of stacktrace.